# ¿como puedo crear una lista con un bucle for y un fetch?

Tags: javascript, ajax

intento consumir una api y quiero que imprima como lista del 0 al 100 pero solo me imprime un valor , que estoy haciendo mal? , intenté haciendolo en unos div y cambiando de lado el bucle for pero me lanza lo mismo siempre

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenido"></div>


    <script>
        var contenido = document.querySelector('#contenido')
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            var i = 0;
            console.log(data.results['0'])
            for(i=0;i<=100;i++){toString(i)
                contenido.innerHTML=`
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        ${data.results[i].name}

                    </li>
                    
                </ol>

            
            `}

        })
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo tienes que poner el signo mas al innerHTML para que agregue asi:

```
contenido.innerHTML+=`
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        ${data.results[i].name}

                    </li>
                    
                </ol>

            
            `
```

y para que te lo enumere correctamente seria asi

```
<body>
    <div id="contenido">
      <ol>

      </ol>
    </div>


    <script>
        var contenido = document.querySelector('#contenido ol')
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            var i = 0;
            console.log(data.results['0'])
            for(i=0;i<=100;i++){toString(i)
                contenido.innerHTML+=`
                
                    <li>
                        ${data.results[i].name}

                    </li>
                    
                

            
            `}

        })
    </script>
    
</body>
```